# To what extent is it precise to evaluate Sympy enormous fractions (Rational)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

I am using Sympy Rational in an algorithm and I am getting enormous factions. Numerator and Denominator grow up to 10000 digits.

I would like to stop the algorithm as soon as the fractions become unevaluable. So the question is, what is the maximum magnitude I can allow for sympy.Rational?

Comment: Please provide an example demonstrating the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The size of SymPy Rationals is limited only by your available memory. If you want an approximate but memory bounded number, use a Float. You can convert a Rational into a Float with `evalf`.